# How to tell Ajax.ActionLink OnSuccess callback which element initiated the ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, unobtrusive-javascript

I want my razor view to look something like this

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("A", "Buy", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "updateLetter" }, new { id = "letter-A" })
@Ajax.ActionLink("B", "Buy", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "updateLetter" }, new { id = "letter-B" })
@Ajax.ActionLink("C", "Buy", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "updateLetter" }, new { id = "letter-C" })
```

and my javascript to look something like this

```
function updateLetter(letter)
{
    $("#letter-" + letter).toggleClass('selected');
}
```

the idea being that if I click the A link, it'll do the ajax and toggle the class on that element. I'm not sure exactly how to hook it up though. What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First fix your `Ajax.ActionLink` overload as yours won't compile.

And to pass parameters you could do this:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "A", 
    "About", 
    null,
    new AjaxOptions { 
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnSuccess = "updateLetter('A')" 
    }, 
    new { 
        id = "letter_A" 
    }
)
```

and then:

```
function updateLetter(letter)
{
    $("#letter-" + letter).toggleClass('selected');
}
```

Personally I am not a fan of the `Ajax.*` helpers. I use an alternative approach which consists of a standard HTML `ActionLink`:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "A", 
    "About", 
    null,
    new { 
        @class = "letter"
        id = "letter_A" 
    }
)
```

which I unobtrusively AJAXify in a separate javascript file:

```
$(function() {
    $('.letter').click(function() {
        var $letter = $(this);
        $.post(this.href, function(result) {
            $letter.toggleClass('selected');
        });
    });
});
```