# using $(this) in a Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, this, actionlink

I need to pass in a function the clicked element using `@Ajax.ActionLink`, this function will be runing at `OnSuccess`, normaly in jQuery we use `$(this)`, but with `@Ajax.ActionLink` does not work.  Is there any other way of doing this ?

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(Model._friends, "HistoryFriends", "Notification", new AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetId="category-result", OnSuccess = "activeThis(this, '.ctg-active')",  OnFailure = "error"})
```

as you can see, I'm trying to pass `this` to the function `activeThis(this, '.ctg-active')`, but can't get it to work.

Comment: get the id, then use getelementbyid

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825295/javascript-onclick-to-get-the-id-of-the-clicked-button

Comment: You're using a string for the callback definition. So you're not passing `this` into the function, `this` is evaluated whenever the string is evaluated. In regular jQuery, you can pass in the object you want to use as `this` as the `context` parameter to the `.ajax` function (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). You might be better off with a definition like this `OnSuccess = function() { activeThis(this, '.ctg-active') }, although I don't know anything about the Callback framework.

Comment: Also see this question and answer for an example of what dotsamuelswan suggests: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6803517/209103